# ojAlgo library: data mismatch bug?

Tags: java, ojalgo

Recently, I start to use ojAlgo library. You can get more information from http://ojalgo.org/index.html.

However, I have a problem when I try to use that. The problem is the stock date and stock price do not match when I want to retrieve the stock data from yahoo finance.

The following is the Java code snippet.

```
YahooSymbol ysymbol = new YahooSymbol("BAC");

DateSeries<BigDecimal> ypriceSeries = ysymbol.getPriceSeries();

System.out.println(ypriceSeries.firstKey() + " " + ypriceSeries.firstValue().toString());
```

The return result is

> Wed May 28 17:00:00 PDT 1986 2.89

But I think the result should be

> Thu May 29 17:00:00 PDT 1986 2.89

As you can see, the date has offset. This problem affect the whole ypriceSeries result. The date of the corresponding stock price is moving backward by one day.

It made the whole stock data is not correct. Anyone has ideas?

Is it a bug or something else? Thanks.

Comment: I have found out the problem is because of the time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you ask this question on the ojAlgo-user mailing list?

https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/ojalgo-user

Comment: it seems the mailing list is dead.